# How to compress root folders (/usr/) from user home directory in linux using script

Tags: shell

Im writing shell script to take backup of nagios (/usr/local/nagios) directory. I'm unable to compress it from my home directory because its a root folder. i cannot use sudo as it asks for password. Is there any better way to zip /ussr/local/ files **without comprimising** security?

Someone please help.

Thank you!

Comment: `to compress it from my home directory` why would current working directory have to do with it? Maybe you mean you are executing some commands as a non-root user without needed permissions? `i cannot use sudo as it asks for password` so disable password?

Comment: i need to zip /usr/local/nagios directory from /home/user1. i cannot use sudo because im writing script and i cannot give password every time

Comment: so disable password? The "i cannot use sudo because I cannot give password every time" seems to me as a not enough reason to not to use sudo. Disable password then for the specific command in sudo.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. Does it affect any security?

Comment: It would really help to understand your problem, if you included the exact cmd-line that you are using and exact text of error messages you get. Also precede that with `pwd` and its output. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a cron job owned by root.

Create this script and save it as `/etc/cron.daily/nagios-backup`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/local
tarball="/home/kart/nagios-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tgz"
tar -pzcf "$tarball" nagios
chmod 400 "$tarball"
```

Make sure that script is executable (`sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/nagios-backup`) and it'll run every night, dumping that log to a dated tarball file in /home/kart. The tarball will not be readable to you without using `sudo` (since your account can't normally see the contents and you requested preserving security).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try this